# Centering a nav menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a menu, it works well but a requirement has come to center the menu options. I have been trying to follow other answers on here but no luck.

you can see the code here
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avMwYO?editors=110

The html is

```
<nav id='menu'>
    <ul>
      <li class='#'>
        <a href='/'>
          Home
        </a>
      </li>
       <li>
        <a href='#'>
         optionOne
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>
          OptionTwo
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

The css is

```
#menu{
background: #f2f2f2;
border-top:2px solid #eaeaea;
border-bottom:2px solid #eaeaea;
color: #444;
height: 50px;
z-index:9;
width:1080px;
margin:0 auto;
}
#menu ul,#menu li{
margin:0 auto;
padding:0 0;
list-style:none
}
#menu ul{
height:80px;
width:1080px
}
#menu li
{
float:left;display:inline;position:relative;font:bold 12px "Arial", sans- serif; text-transform:none;}
#menu a{display: block;
line-height: 50px;
padding: 0 30px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #444;
border-right:1px solid #ddd;

}

 li.home a{background:none;}
```

If anyone could explain how I can achieve this I would be grateful

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the floats from the `li`, make them `inline-block` and add `text-align:center` to the parent `ul`.

```
#menu ul {
  height: 80px;
  width: 1080px;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font: bold 12px "Arial", sans-serif;
  text-transform: none;
}
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/qOvXBr?editors=110)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
#menu{
background: #f2f2f2;
border-top:2px solid #eaeaea;
border-bottom:2px solid #eaeaea;
color: #444;
height: 50px;
z-index:9;
width:1080px;
text-align:center;
}
#menu ul,#menu li{margin:0 auto;padding:0 0;list-style:none}
#menu ul{height:80px;}
#menu li
{
display:inline-block;font:bold 12px "Arial", sans-serif; text-transform:none;}
#menu a{display: block;
line-height: 50px;
padding: 0 30px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #444;
border-right:1px solid #ddd;

}

li.home a{background:none;}
```

Change your CSS to this. demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVZrGO?editors=110